# The service "acme.file_uploader" has a dependency on a non-existent service "request"

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-3.3

I'm working on symfony3 and I have added below code in services.yml file

```
    punk_ave.file_uploader:
    class: FD\PatientBundle\Services\FileUploader
    public: true
    arguments:
      - file_base_path: '%file_uploader.file_base_path%'
        web_base_path: '%file_uploader.web_base_path%'
        request: '@request'
        #file_manager: '@punk_ave.file_uploader_file_manager'
        allowed_extensions: '%file_uploader.allowed_extensions%'
        #sizes: '%file_uploader.sizes%'
        originals: '%file_uploader.originals%'
        max_number_of_files: '%file_uploader.max_number_of_files%'
    scope: request
```

And I'm getting this error:

> The service "acme.file_uploader" has a dependency on a non-existent service "request".

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with "request" arguments?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just get rid of whatever tutorial you happen to be using.  @request went away years ago so it is completely out of date.  This is just the first of many issues that you will run into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service `@request` doesn't exists, maybe you want `@request_stack` ?

```
request: '@request_stack'
```

If you don't knpw exactly, try to launch into your command line:

```
bin/console debug:container
```

and you can see all your available service

Comment: I have run this command on cmd: "php bin/console debug:container"
But, getting same error message. Don't know how to solve this error

Comment: ok so you didn't find request service right? maybe is request_stack ? try it please

Comment: Like Alessandro said, use `@request_stack`. `@request` was deprecated with 2.8 afaik and got removed in 3. You can access the `Request` object in your service like described here: `https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/request.html` (you can use `getCurrentRequest` or `getMasterRequest` depending on your needs)

Comment: Great! If this solved your problem accept the answer to help other person with your same problem please @mobizen

Answer (score 1):

```
request: '@request'
```

This line means that you call a non-existent `request` service.